# Using HOGDescriptor in EmguCV

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

I am using EmguCV to detect pedestrians. When i try to use HOGDescriptor i got an error in function DetectMultiScale(My_Image):

Cannot implicitly convert typeEmgu.CV.Structure.MCvObjectDetection[]' to 'System.Drawing.Rectangle[]'

```
        OpenFileDialog Openfile = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (Openfile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            //Load the Image
            Image<Bgr, Byte> My_Image = new Image<Bgr, byte>(Openfile.FileName);

            Rectangle[] regions;

            using (HOGDescriptor des = new HOGDescriptor())
            {
                des.SetSVMDetector(HOGDescriptor.GetDefaultPeopleDetector());
                regions = des.DetectMultiScale(My_Image);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

As the error suggests you can not directly convert object of type MCvObjectDetection[] as Rectangle[] object. But MCvObjectDetection is a structure which has Rectangle as  member variable. So you must code like this

`typeEmgu.CV.Structure.MCvObjectDetection[] objects=des.DetectMultiScale(My_Image);`

then get list of rectangles by a loop

```
for(int i=0; i<objects.length;i++) 
{ 
regions[i]=objects[i].Rect; 
}
```

https://sourceforge.net/p/emgucv/svn/1442/tree/trunk/Emgu.CV/PInvoke/CvType/MCvObjectDetection.cs#l22 is a reference to MCvObjectDetection structure.